# How should we tag questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

What should be the main tags on the site?

Tagging by game is obvious, any question specific to a game should be tagged.

I don't see the point of board/card tags; they supply very little information and many posts won't have them.  Perhaps if a question is not game specific then that would work.

`house-rules` is a great tag.  Could we use `rules-as-written` or perhaps just `rules` for rule questions that don't invite people to write their own rules?

PS this would be community-wiki if I could.  At least I don't get rep for it!

Comment: I like just `rules` for clarifications on existing rules, personally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why we need a `house-rules` or a `rules` tag at all (or `tactics` or `strategy` or `board-games`). I consider all of these meta-tags that do not add value to the questions. See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ for more.

I can't imagine myself ever wanting to search by "house-rules" to find all the various house-rules people have come up with. I would want to search by a specific game.

In my opinion, *most* questions should have 1 tag - the game they are asking about. I'm not seeing much value from the extra tags.

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9386) (on Gaming) is a question where it makes sense to have 2 different tags -  It's about combining 2 different specific things into 1 question.

Comment: Damn, when you're right, you're right.

Comment: I'm torn on this.  I can see where you're coming from, but I do kind of like viewing `dominion` and then seeing the subtags of stuff people are asking about within the `dominion` tag.

Comment: I disagree. Having a `rules` tag might be good for someone who's a rules lawyer and wants to highlight questions about rules, since they're good at figuring out rule intricacies. Some people are interested in only the official rules, and may ignore `house-rules` questions. Some people may be more interested in talking about strategy than rules, and follow the `strategy` tag. There are plenty of reasons to have tags beyond just the game name; you might be asking about a whole genre while using one game as an example, or you might just have interests that are finer grained than an entire game.

Comment: I also disagree. What about if I wanted to see all questions that have specific game tag and `house-rules`, just to find out what kind of modifications people make to rules of this game? How about this: I'm preparing to teach some people rules of the game X. If I type in search field `[X] [rules]` I will get questions about rules clarification in the game X. That's exactly what I wanted - I was looking for the list of rules, that might be most confusing to other players. Why take this option away?

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing a `board-game` tag that I think is unnecessary.  This site is for board games, card games, things like Dominion that feel like both at once.  Anyone interested in a particular game can easily discover which specific type of game it is - this tag just clutters things up.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see your mention of this in the OP.

Comment: What if people want to search for all questions about board games?

Comment: Hm. I have a hard time seeing that as a likely use case - why would they need to know about all board games ever?  Just to look for questions to answer, maybe?

Comment: @lilserf Exactly, if they're interested in board games but not card games (or the other way around), which is rather common. We should also probably have a separate tag for card games that use poker cards instead of special cards

Comment: I'm still unconvinced that this will provide enough usefulness to offset the fact that nearly EVERY question will have one of the two tags on it, and that some games (like Dominion) will be difficult to classify.  If every question is tagged either A or B, do those tags really need to exist?

Comment: @lilserf If an asker had six tags they wanted to use and needed to drop one, I would say drop board/card-games, but if you've got five spaces why not use them? It's not like it takes up more space on the page, the tags are in one row either way, and we're going to end up with the same [problem](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109/why-is-there-a-linux-tag) as on the Unix SE where half the posts have [unix] or [linux] tags and the other half don't. (Also, you can use @Mic to [reply to my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020))

Comment: I like this type of tag but this is clearly a meta tag and meta tags don't use to be well accept on other sites.

Comment: @bigown I'm not super attached to it (and it sounds like we're going to end up not using it), but it's definitely not a meta tag; it's a tag about the game in question itself, not about the post

Comment: I don't like it because it will be the subset of all questions about board games that the questioner has remembered to tag board-games.  It's about as pointful as a loops tag on SO for every question that involves a loop.

Comment: These tags seem like the perfect example of a useless meta-tag as seen in [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 1):

We need create a standard to some words. We already have **boardgames**, **board-games** and **board-game**.

For me the correct is **board-games**

Comment: I retagged a "variations" to "house-rules" already.

Comment: @Richard: English is not my native language, so I know little about some expressions. I just learnt it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tactics vs Strategy?  Do we need both as tags?

Comment: On a purely pedantic level, they can be quite different.  Not sure how often they really are different in most board or card games though.

Comment: Someone has a good example to keep both?

Comment: @lilserf There is a difference, but I doubt how much they will be used differently.  Strategy seems to have a lot more use so far.

Comment: Yeah, and the average user will probably not care about the difference.  I think `strategy` is likely to be the more common tag.

Comment: For most that do care, `doctrine` is what is really meant rather than tactics, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who remember them, can we use the old Avalon Hill three character abbreviations as tags - DIP, CIV, ACV, A3R, 3R4, or should we tag more like `diplomacy`, `civilization`, `advanced-civilization`, `advanced-third-reich`, `third-reich-fourth-edition`?

Comment: I think generally the full name of the game is the better tag - it will be easier to _find_ questions that way for Google and for the casual reader. I believe we can set up aliases so that if someone tries to tag a question with DIP, it automagically becomes diplomacy - anyone have a link for that?

Comment: Full names of the games are more consistent with the other SE communities as well. Additionally, if someone types "dip" into the tag box they're going to get autocompletion to "diplomacy" right away and see our pattern.

Comment: But the odder codes would make good tag synonyms.   Agreed.

Comment: @Erik http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: See also http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/81/should-the-threshold-for-suggesting-tag-synonyms-be-lowered