# Do we have an official position on the meta-tag question?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There was a lot of discussion and disagreement about meta-tags [here](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/159), but it doesn't seem like a consensus was reached.

A recent question of mine just had the board-games tag added. My preference is not to use that tag as I don't think it really adds value, as it will be used so much. My gut reaction was to remove it, but obviously that person thinks it should be there. They have no way to know I deliberately chose not to use that tag. I could just remove it, but I don't want to start a retagging battle either (not that it would be likely to happen).

So, should we be using tags like board-games and rules, or not?

Comment: Note that part of this discussion is moot now, as board-games and card-games have been [blacklisted](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/398/should-we-use-the-tag-delete-me-or-remove-this-tag/399#399).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we've reached enough critical mass yet to definitely answer many questions like this.  The few people talking on meta do not always well represent the full user base IMHO.

My preference would be to let the site organically develop and see what proves useful over time to most users.

That said, you should feel free to rollback the tag change if you do not agree/like it.  FWIW, I do not tag my questions with either `board-games` or `rules`

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much agree with your opinion in the question, and with Pat's answer.  I wanted to add that I think there is some merit in the board-games/card-games tags provided they are used sparingly for questions that aren't about particular games, but which are asking about board games and *not* card games (or vice versa).